Shapely multilinestring: depth first search
I have a Shapely multiline string that has multiple branches that I want removed. I've attached an image where the red is the main line that I want to keep and the black are to be removed.
I can't filter based on individual linestring lengths as some segments that need to be kept are shorter than the branches.
I was thinking a Depth-First Search would be appropriate but I'm unsure how to implement it when working with a shapely object. As well as calculate the full length of the main line.
Any tips would be appreciated.


The pygeoops library has a function to create a centerline from a polygon that also cleans up short branches,... You can use/checke out the (private) functions used by this functionality, they implement this: _centerline source code

Thanks @Pieter this branched line is the best output I got from pygeoops.centerline and still needs further cleaning for my purposes so this could be helpful.
Also, is there a way to make centerline have the line terminate at the polygon edge?

normally the options to finetune the result are available via the parameters of pygeoops.centerline (mainly min_branch_length)... I suppose you tried those?

Regarding the option to have the centerline touch the polygon edge, that features has recently been added, and is available in the alpha version of pygeoops via the extend parameter (centerline latest doc). You can install it with pip install pygeoops==0.5.0a1

If the purpose is to keep one multiline, then why not look for the longest path and reject anything that is not on it?
